# Restore Deleted Navigation Property in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I deleted a navigation property in my Entity Framework Designer, thinking it wasn't needed.  It's now needed and I'd like to restore it. How can I do this without deleting the model and re-importing the table from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just refresh the model (the same way you add to it), so there's no need to delete it first. And if the navigation property doesn't get added you can add it manually.

Comment: Refreshing doesn't add it.  It seems that the designer remembers what's been deleted. How can I add it manually?

Comment: Right click in de EDM, choose Add, choose Assocation.

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't exact, but pretty close and pointed me in the right direction. I first needed to add an navigation property.  Then right click on the navigation property and change the "Association".